# Running Python script in my Windows .bat file

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a .bat file, in the file I did:

1. cd to a direcotry
2. copied the files to another directory
3. run the `to-csv.vb` program on the files
4. deleted some files
5. cd to another direction
6. run my Python script.

I'm stuck at step 6.  Here is my code:

```
cd "Python\test1"
copy  "Python\test1\"*.xls*  "Python\test1\move"

FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('DIR *.xls* /b') DO to-csv.vbs "%%i" "%%i.csv" 
del "H2*.csv"
del "H6*.csv"
del "H3*.xlsx"

cd "H:\UCLAHealth\HIIN\Data Process\Python" #my python script1 is in this directory 

python script1.py  #this line didn't work.
```

I'm ok with steps 1-5, but stuck on step 6. What's the correct syntax for running a Python script in .bat file?

Comment: Looks OK. Are you getting an error message? What does it say?

Comment: If the directory the python executable is in isn't in your `PATH` environment variable, you will need to add the full path to it to the command: i.e. something like `"C:\Python\python.exe" script1.py`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either do this in your script:

```
set "python=C:\path to Python\python.exe"
"%python%" script1.py
```

Or you can execute it with full path:

```
"C:\Path to Python\python.exe" script1.py
```

Comment: In my case I have no idea if the user has the python.exe in the PATH variable or where the installation path of python.exe. Any ideas ?

Comment: @thanos.a `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('where /R c:\ python.exe') do set python_path=%%i & (call)` then `"%python_path%" script.py` or just `echo "%python_path%"` if you want see the path.